# How to unit test conditional (branch) inside component render (before return)

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I have set a conditional "return null" if no data is found for a function invocation inside my table component render (before return) so that it won't break (extra safety layer)

My problem is that I'm struggling to test this, and my branch coverage needs to 100%.

Easy to test if I make it a function, but I want to avoid using parenthesis everywhere inside props. Also easy to test if I move it above the render, but then the whole point is missed (to stop render from breaking in case data fails to fetch from API)

```
  const data = this.getData()
  if (!data) return null
  return (
```

I only need to cover the if `!(data)` return null

(`getData()` method already has an early null return)

Comment: try returning false;

Comment: FFS, my first line got cut off.

It was supposed to show:

```
render() {
  const data = this.getData()
  if (!data) return null
  return (
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I'd approach it is to test the render result of the component. For example, in your case if `data` is null, does it render anything? The you can check in tests if component (or its part) is properly rendered.

Comment: Thanks Clarity! Found a way to test the actual return value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `react-testing-library` and test HTML output. This is an awesome library that allows you to unit/integration test your components like 'user would interact with them'.

https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/intro

Comment: Thanks Łukasz! Unfortunately this is part of work and I can't just add libraries. 
We already have a pretty good setup, but I was just struggling to wrap my head around the "inside-render" problem, because that const is unreachable by Jest.
Managed to solve it though!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for replying so quickly! I found a solution that properly tests and passes our SonarQube rules:

```
it('should return null if there is no data', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<MyComponent />)
    const instance = wrapper.instance()
    instance.getData = jest.fn()
    const renderedWrapper = instance.render()
    expect(renderedWrapper).toBeNull()
})
```